# Apache and parsed PHP caching

Tags: php, linux, apache, web

Assume that we have Linux + Apache + PHP installed with all default settings. I have some PHP website that uses some large thirdparty PHP library, let's say 1 Mb of PHP sources. This library is used very rarely, let's say for POST requests only. There is a reason why I can't move this library usage into separate PHP file. So, I have to include this library for each HTTP request, but use it very rarely. Should I concern about time spend for PHP parsing in that case? Let me explain. I could do this:

```
<?php
require_once('heavy_library.php');
// do regular stuff
if(we need heavy library)
{
    heavy_library_function();
}
?>
```

I assume that this solution is bad because in this case heavy_library.php is parsed for each HTTP request. I can move it into the if statement:

```
<?php
// do regular stuff
if(we need heavy library)
{
    require_once('heavy_library.php');
    heavy_library_function();
}
?>
```

Now as I understand it it's being parsed only in case when we need the library.

Now, get back to the question. Default settings for Apache and PHP. Should I concern about this issue? Should I move require_once into the place where it is really being used, or I can leave it as usual and Apache / PHP will do some kind of caching that will prevent parsing for each HTTP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Apache will not do the caching.  You should keep the `require_once` inside the `if` so it is only used when you need it.

If you do want caching of PHP, then look at something like [eaccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/).

Comment: You're welcome.  Jack pointed out APC in his answer below, but I haven't used it.  I have used eaccelerator in production and development for years and it's performed flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

When you tell PHP to `require()` something, it will do it no matter what; the only thing that prevents parsing that file from scratch every time will be to use an opcode cache such as [APC](http://www.php.net/apc).

Conditionally loading the file would be preferred in this case. If you're worried about making life more complicated by having these conditions, perform a small benchmark.

You could also use autoloading to load files "on demand" automatically; see [`spl_autoload`](http://www.php.net/spl_autoload)

Comment: Thanks for spl_autoload, didn't know about it.